# biblatex. article: crossref and strings

Tags: biblatex

1. If I want to cite a few `articles` from the same journal, and I don't want to type the same `journal={...}` for each entry. Is there a way to achieve this like for `@book` and `@mvbook` via `crossref`?
2. There are two given fields `volume` and `number` for `@article`. But in german there are besides the correlating `Band` and `Nummer` also the strings `Jahrgang` (=bibstring `jourvol`) and `Heft` (no bibstring yet). Are there other ways to write them for special articles (not all!!) - besides putting them in the fields like `volume = {Jahrgang 69}`?

**Update**, Questions 1 was solved by Ulrike Fischer, as you can see in the following MWE. (I still wonder why there doesn't exist an entrytype `@journal`.)

@Question 2: The problem is: In german some journals write `Heft`, some write `Nummer`. In english there maybe only exists `number` for both. But I need to distinguish between them and use both cases in my work!

Of course I can put `H.` or `Heft` in the field `number`, as shown in the MWE, *myarticle*. But I always think hardcoding isn't the best solution.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{myjournal,
journaltitle = {Archiv für Musikwissenschaft},
publisher = {Franz Steiner Verlag},
year = {2009},
}

@article{myarticle,
crossref = {myjournal},
title = {Dummy title},
author = {Dummy author},
number = {H. 1},
volume = {66. Jahrg.},

pages = {50-100},
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/dummyurl},
urldate = {2014-05-01}
}

@article{myarticleB,
journaltitle = {Archiv für Wissenschaft},
publisher = {Anderer Verlag},
year = {1919},
title = {Dummy titleTwo},
author = {Dummy authorTwo},
number = {Nr. 6},
volume = {36},
pages = {150-200},
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/dummyurl2},
urldate = {2014-05-01}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4 paper,12pt, german]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{myarticle}\nocite{myarticleB}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `jourvol` is not a field, the `\do{jourvol}` you find in `biblatex2.sty` is to create a bibstring `jourvol`. According to the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 204 §4.9.2.10 *Publication Details*, `jourvol` contains "The term ‘volume’, referring to a journal."

Comment: Your entry is confusing: it is an `@book` and yet you want a `journal` field?  I'd expect `@article` with `journal`, `volume`, (perhaps) `number`, etc.

Comment: Jon is quite right. Either you have a `@book` in a `series` (and a `number` within that `series`), or a specific volume of a multi-volume book. Or you have an `@article` with a `journal` and a simple `volume` (and `number`). Plus, the macro you redefine is only called in the `@article` driver, not the `@book` one, so your MWE will print the `jourvol` anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing MWE, I tried to clarify my question/problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want to see?  It sounds like you want the strings written out, and I must admit I don't fully understand how Band, Nummer, Jahrgang, and Heft are all related; I thought Band/Jahrgang and Nummer/Heft were different pairs of words for about the same thing...

Comment: Could you please give a real-word example for your second problem? While I have seen "Jahrgang" and "Heft", these often have a one-to-one correspondence to `volume` and `number` - I think. Indeed the bibstring `jourvol` can be used to precede the `volume` field for `@articles` (it does not replace the `volume` field in any way; for other types, `volume` would be preceded by the bibstring `volume`).

Comment: As I have commented on Ulrike Fischer's post, `@periodical` might be a match for the `@journal` entry type.

Comment: So you want the `volume` and `number` field preceded by their bibtsrings (`volume`: "Band" and `number`: "Nummer") in some cases and by "Jahrgang" and "Heft" in other cases? This will make the bibliography slightly inconsistent, but the information might be closer to the form given in the actual publication. Anyway, you will have to find a way to tell `biblatex` to distinguish these two types of entries.

Comment: You could use `journalsubtitle` for Jahrgang and `issue` for Heft.  There is also `issuetitle` and `issuesubtitle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ad 1)

You can use the `crossref` mechanism as one would expect.
`@article`-to-`@article` inheritance has no special rules, so the default rules apply. That means almost all fields are copied one-to-one to the `crossref`ing entry, if they do not exist there already. (Please refer to appendix B *Default Inheritance Setup*, pp. 242-244 and §2.4.1 *Cross-referencing*, pp. 35-37 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) fore more details).

So here

```
@periodical{myjournal,
  title       = {Archiv für Musikwissenschaft},
  publisher   = {Franz Steiner Verlag},
  options     = {dataonly},
}

@article{myarticleA1,
  crossref  = {myjournal},
  title     = {Dummy title},
  author    = {Dummy author},
  number    = {1},
  volume    = {66},
  year      = {2009},
  pages     = {50-100},
  url       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/dummyurl},
  urldate   = {2014-05-01},
  options   = {jourvol=true},
}

@article{myarticleA2,
  crossref  = {myarticleA1},
  title     = {Dummy title A1},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {120-130},
  url       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/dummyurl2},
  options   = {jourvol=true},
}
```

`myarticleA2` is going to inherit the `author`, `volume`, `journal`, `year`, `urldate` of `myarticleA1` (`myarticleA1` inherited the `journaltitle` from `myjournal`); the `options` field is not inherited though, so we had to re-add it.

The "parent" `@periodical` `myjournal` can be `crossref`ed by every `@article` in the "Archiv für Musikwissenschaft" journal; in this case this does not save us a lot of typing, as effectively the only piece of information copied from `myjournal` is the `journaltitle` field (notice how the field is `title` in a `@periodical`, it will be copied to the `journaltitle` of an `@article`). It might be a good idea to make the `@periodical` `dataonly`, so it does not accidentally appear in the bibliography as a separate item.

So you can either `crossref` several `@article`s to save typing, or create a "parent" `@periodical` to `crossref` to, or you can use both.

<sub>You might see now why there is no `@journal` entry type. One hardly ever wants a (bare) journal to appear in the bibliography and the amount of information inherited from a prospective `@journal` entry type is not that big.</sub>

### Ad 2)

If you want some `@article`s to display "Band" and "Nummer" (volume and number, respecticely) and some to display "Jahrgang" and "Heft", we will first have to tell `biblatex` which entries get which treatment.

We will do this via a simple option, you can add to the `options` list: The option is called `jourvol`

```
\newtoggle{bib@jourvol} % fallback is false
\DeclareEntryOption{jourvol}[true]{\settoggle{bib@jourvol}{#1}}
```

The "Jahrgang" bibstring already exists (`jourvol`), but we will need to declare one for "Heft", let's call it `journum`.

```
\NewBibliographyString{journum}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{journum = {Heft}}
```

If you want to be able to define short and long forms of the bibstring, we cannot use `\DefineBibliographyStrings`, but have to use `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`, the latter command can only be used in an `.lbx` file, so we have to define a new one for that (the two lines above become superfluous with the `.lbx` file).

Your `.lbx` file will look like this, basically everything is inherited from `ngerman`, but we add the new bibstring `journum` and populate it.

```
\ProvidesFile{ngerman-jour.lbx}[2014/05/01 ngerman with journum]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
\NewBibliographyString{journum}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit   = {ngerman},
  journum   = {{Heft}{H\adddot}},
}
```

The `lbx` file must be put somewhere LaTeX can find it - in the MWE below it will be created with `filecontents`, if you plan to use it more often, you really should save it in an appropriate directory.
It can then be loaded via `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-jour}`.

Now we can use the option to decide whether to use `jourvol`/`journum` or `volume`/`number`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\iftoggle{bib@jourvol}{\bibstring{jourvol}}{\bibstring{volume}}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\iftoggle{bib@jourvol}{\bibstring{journum}}{\bibstring{number}}~#1}
```

Finally, we get rid of the dot between `volume` and `number` and add a comma and a space

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

You can now choose whether you want "Jahrgang"/"Heft" or "Band"/"Nummer" via the `jourvol` option: Add `options = {jourvol=true}` (or the simpler but equivalent `options = {jourvol}`) to get "Jahrgang"/"Heft" and add `ptions = {jourvol=false}` (or just don't mention `jourvol` in options, the default is `jourvol=false`) to get "Band"/"Nummer".

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@periodical{myjournal,
  title       = {Archiv für Musikwissenschaft},
  publisher   = {Franz Steiner Verlag},
  options     = {dataonly},
}

@article{myarticleA1,
  crossref  = {myjournal},
  title     = {Dummy title},
  author    = {Dummy author},
  number    = {1},
  volume    = {66},
  year      = {2009},
  pages     = {50-100},
  url       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/dummyurl},
  urldate   = {2014-05-01},
  options   = {jourvol=true},
}

@article{myarticleA2,
  crossref  = {myarticleA1},
  title     = {Dummy title A1},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {120-130},
  url       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/dummyurl2},
  options   = {jourvol=true},
}

@article{myarticleB,
  journaltitle  = {Archiv für Wissenschaft},
  publisher     = {Anderer Verlag},
  year          = {1919},
  title         = {Dummy titleTwo},
  author        = {Dummy authorTwo},
  number        = {6},
  volume        = {36},
  pages         = {150-200},
  url           = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/dummyurl2},
  urldate       = {2014-05-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4 paper,12pt, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bib@jourvol} % fallback is false
\DeclareEntryOption{jourvol}[true]{\settoggle{bib@jourvol}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{ngerman-jour.lbx}
    \ProvidesFile{ngerman-jour.lbx}[2014/05/01 ngerman with journum]
    \InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}
    \NewBibliographyString{journum}
    \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
      inherit   = {ngerman},
      journum   = {{Heft}{H\adddot}},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-jour}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\iftoggle{bib@jourvol}{\bibstring{jourvol}}{\bibstring{volume}}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\iftoggle{bib@jourvol}{\bibstring{journum}}{\bibstring{number}}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply try it out? crossref works fine for me:

```
@article{journal,
    journal = {a journal},
    number ={3}}

@article{authora,
 author={authora},
 crossref={journal},
 pages={5-10}}
```

When I cite authora it pulls the informations from journal.

Comment: I don't know and didn't test if you need the same entrytype. But as you wanted to add journal informations it seemed sensible to use a type which knows the journal field.

Comment: @musicman One could of course use the `@periodical` entry type as the "parent", but there seems to be no problem in `crossref`ing several `@article`s.